# Illustrator variables - dynamically line up two text strings next to each other when autogenerating

Tags: automation, adobe-illustrator

I am automating the generation of several thousand labels in Adobe Illustrator. The use of the VariableImporter script has made easy work of it so far, but now I have reached an issue where I am stumped. The original plan worked great, until the powers that be requested that one line of text have a bold text string, followed by a normal weight text string. Before, when the font weights were the same I could have connected the two strings of text in the CSV file prior to loading them into the drawing, and they would have came out lying right next to each other. This is now no longer possible and I can't think of a solution that is not incredibly fussy.

I don't know illustrator very well, so I am thinking I could just be unaware of some setting that would stick an object next to another one even as the other one moves.

Comment: Any ideas or advice are appreciated. I am afraid that there might not be an amazing silver bullet solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to accomplish this by having a script do some processing during the course of your batch output, and an organizational system which adds some overhead to your file, in terms of adding more text boxes and possibly an extra layer to your document. But - here's what you can have: a hidden layer with all your variables there in separate single point-text objects, and a layer with your regular template objects such as any point text or area-text objects. Your art text objects will need to be re-worked to contain a string with multiple variable placeholders like this: `"Hello, <FirstName> <LastName>"`. The placeholders can be styled, and a processing script would then need to replace the `<placeholder>` words with your real variable values. Where are the varible values? They are going to be populating into your hidden layer which has your separate text objects and the script would need to read the contents of each of those to put into the `<placeholders>`. ~~Those same text fields can be styled as you wish, and the script could apply the same styles to your text when it is replaced in the main text body.~~ -actually this won't be necessary of your routine backs up the original text frame with the placeholder in it, therefore preserving the styling, but it may be necessary if you are going to instead use an external text file to keep your original text in. And of course, it will need to make a backup of the original text with all the `<placeholders>` so that it will reset the text for every new dataset during your batch process.

However, this is much easier done in Indesign, can you not use ID for your task?

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Using ID could be done, but this is the first project of this kind that I am doing and I don't want to change too much in the way of how everyone has been doing things. If I get too many more snags then I will probably just switch to using ID. I've already gone this far with Illustrator, I can't give it up now ! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You need some help with the script I describe?

Comment: Yes I could use some help with the script. I don't know the first thing about writing a script for illustrator.

Comment: Basically from what I understand I have to load the two pieces of text into a hidden layer as I have done with the variable importer script and cut and paste it into the placeholder which is formatted in the way it needs to be formatted ie "**<boldDescription>** - <description>" using a script.

Comment: Well have you written other scripts before? To replace text and keep styling you have to interact with some of the Illustrator scripting's textFrame and textRange objects, etc. Here is a thread where they talk about changing text but preserving the style: https://forums.adobe.com/message/8938899#8938899

Comment: I have not written a script for Illustrator at all, only used them. I know JavaScript but am not familiar with using it in Illustrator. Right now I am trying to make that script pull the variable's data from the data set

Comment: so that I can run what there is there with the data set's variable data

Comment: Yea, now you're in it! So there is no way to read the variable data from the dataset - hence you'll have to employ a hidden layer which contains your bound text objects, from which your processing script will pull the data. This cumbersome way is how you can read the data from datasets and apply wherever.

Comment: Would this work as well?
`var idoc = app.activeDocument;
var ivar = idoc.variables.getByName ('variableName');
variableContents = ivar.pageItems[0].contents;` now variableContents has a value of the variable's contents, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Okay here is the way I figured out how to do this with help from Adobe forums and from Vasily.

First of all, use InDesign if possible. It is better at performing a Data Merge and can do this without your scripting.

Write out `<variable1> <variable2>` which is formatted as needed on the same line of text.

You will need to have the variables that you are putting in there somewhere in the illustration. Recommended to put it in a hidden layer behind everything.

replace variable1 and variable2 with the names of your variables where the functions getVariableContents() are called in this script

```
var idoc = app.activeDocument;
var vars = idoc.variables;

var replace1 = /<variable1>/g;
var replace2 = /<variable2>/g;

// author CarlosCanto on adobe forums
function getVariableContents(variableName) {
    var idoc = app.activeDocument;
    var ivar = idoc.variables.getByName(variableName);
    return ivar.pageItems[0].contents;
}

var replaceWith1 = getVariableContents('variable1'), result;
var replaceWith2 = getVariableContents('variable2'), result;

// regex_changeContentsOfWordOrString_RemainFormatting.jsx
// regards pixxxel schubser
function exchangeWords(s, replacer) {
    var s = s;
    var replacer = replacer;

    var atfs = activeDocument.textFrames;
    for (var i = atfs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        atf = atfs[i];
        while (result = s.exec(atf.contents)) {
            try {
                aCon = atf.characters[result.index];
                    aCon.length = result[0].length;
                    aCon.contents = aCon.contents.replace(s, replacer);
            } catch (e) {};
        }
    }
}

exchangeWords(replace1,replaceWith1);
exchangeWords(replace2,replaceWith2);
```

run the script

Answer (score 1):

I modified script from @tucker-david-grebitus's answer. So now it gets all textual variables and replaces all their names edged by percent symbol

```
for (var i = activeDocument.variables.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    var variable = activeDocument.variables[i];
    if (variable.kind !== VariableKind.TEXTUAL || !variable.pageItems.length) {
        continue;
    }

    var search = new RegExp('%' + variable.name + '%', 'g');
    var value = variable.pageItems[0].contents;

    for (var j = activeDocument.textFrames.length - 1; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
        var textFrame = activeDocument.textFrames[j];
        textFrame.contents = textFrame.contents.replace(search, value);
    }
}
```